# Can Firebase handle multiple types of user accounts?

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I’m looking into using Firebase for my next project, however i need multiple user account types (admin and standard user). Does Firebase’s user authentication support multiple user types? If so, how would I check the user type, and inversely set the user type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Auth accounts don't discriminate between user types, nor does it offer any profile settings for that.  User type is a concept that you have to implement for yourself using your own definitions of "admin" or "standard" or whatever it is you need.